# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in python while checking the item in a list

Tags: python

```
 File "C:\Users\sakre\Documents\Dummy.py", line 330, in <module>
    print find_path_to_friend(net, "John", "Ollie")
  File "C:\Users\sakre\Documents\Dummy.py", line 304, in find_path_to_friend
    path = get_path_recursive(network,toTraverseList[0],user_B,path,traversedList,toTraverseList)
  File "C:\Users\sakre\Documents\Dummy.py", line 286, in get_path_recursive
    if destination  in network[current]['connections']:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am trying to check if a time is in the list of not but it is showing type error and it is working fine for following case

```
def add_connection(network, user_A, user_B):
    if user_B not in network[user_A]['connections']:
        network[user_A]['connections'].append(user_B)
    return network
```

Comment: Your exception is coming from a different part of the code than the function you've shown. You need to look at `current` in `get_path_recursive`.

Comment: You can't use a `list` as a key in a dictionary. It looks like `current` is a `list` instead of a `tuple` or some other hashable type (and as @Blckknght points out - it's not this section of code).

Comment: Thank @Blckknght, I was passing a list instead of list item